# Как правильно переопределить метод onAuthenticationSuccess?

Tags: spring, безопасность, java

Как правильно переопределить метод onAuthenticationSuccess, чтобы получить логин пользователя, который только что залогинился, чтобы по этому логину вывести всю информацию о пользователе из базы (профиль пользователя)? Пока выводится пустой профиль (profile.jsp).

**класс Authentication:**

```
     public class Authentication implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {
            @Override
            public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
                                                HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse,
                                                Authentication authentication)
                    throws IOException, ServletException {

//что здесь написать?

            }
           }
```

**класс UserDaoImpl:**

```
@Repository
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {
  @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
...
//в базе ищется введенный пользователем логин
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public User getLogin(String login){
        return (User) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(
        "FROM User where login=:login").setParameter("login", login).uniqueResult();
    }

}
```

**класс UserServiceImpl:**

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService{

@Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;
    ...
      @Transactional
    public User getLogin(String login){
        return userDao.getLogin(login);
    }

}
```

**класс UserController:**

```
@Controller
public class UserController {

 @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    ...

  @RequestMapping(value = "/user/profile", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String profile(@RequestParam("findUser") String userLogin, ModelMap model, HttpSession session) {

        session.setAttribute("userLogin", login);
        model.put("user", (userService.getLogin(userLogin)));
        return "profile";
    }

   }
```

**profile.jsp**

```
<body>

        <table class="user-table">
                <tr>
                <th><spring:message code="label.name"/></th>
                <th><spring:message code="label.surname"/></th>
                <th><spring:message code="label.birthdate"/></th>
                <th><spring:message code="label.address"/></th>
                <th><spring:message code="label.tel"/></th>
                <th><spring:message code="label.email"/></th>
                <th><spring:message code="label.login"/></th>
                <th><spring:message code="label.category"/></th>
                <%--<th><spring:message code="label.password"/></th>--%>
                <th>&nbsp;</th>
            </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>${user.name}</td>
                    <td>${user.surname}</td>
                    <td><calendar:formatDate
                    value="${user.birthdate}" pattern="dd-MM-yyyy"/></td>
                    <td>${user.address}</td>
                    <td>${user.tel}</td>
                    <td>${user.email}</td>
                    <td>${user.login}</td>
                    <%--<td>${user.password}</td>--%>
                    <td>${user.category.name}</td>

                    <td><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/user/edit/${user.id}">
                    <spring:message code="label.edit"/></a></td>

                </tr>

        </table>

           </body>
```

**spring-security.xml:**

```
           ...
        <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">

                <headers>
                    <cache-control />
                </headers>

                <intercept-url pattern="/admin**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />

                <form-login login-page="/login" 
                    default-target-url="/home"
                    authentication-failure-url="/login?error" 
                    username-parameter="login"
                    password-parameter="password"
                    login-processing-url="/auth/login_check"
                    authentication-success-handler-ref="AuthenticationSuccessHandler"/>

                <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />
                <csrf />

            </http>    
           ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onAuthenticationSuccess` использовать не хочешь ты. Это совсем не о том.

В контроллере просто вызовете `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()` и из него получите информацию о текущем пользователе.

Если используете последнюю версию Spring Security, то можете [использовать аннотацию `@AuthenticationPrincipal`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-authentication-principal).